# Filtering a list of doubles and applying a function to that result

Tags: haskell

[92.0, 81.0, 81.0, 41.0, 69.0, 95.0, 82.0, 25.0, 92.0, 18.0, 60.0, 68.0, 29.0, 75.0, 87.0, 24.0, 99.0, 93.0, 76.0, 49.0, 36.0]

Test list is above

Basically I am given a list of numbers, I am to extract groups of three then apply a function to that to get my answer. I cannot use import either or recursion.

"takes a list of Doubles, treats each consecutive group of three Doubles as the lengths of the three sides of a triangle, uses triangle_area to calculate its area; and after processing all Doubles in the list, returns all calculated areas as a list of Doubles."

```
triangle_area :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
triangle_area a b c = sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) where s = (a +           b + c) / 2.0

triangle_areas :: [Double] -> [Double]
triangle_areas xs = []
```

I was going to use filter on that list but does not work with doubles.In the given lists the sets of three with represent(a,b,c) for the triangle_area function. I will then need to apply the triangle_area function to those numbers.

not sure how to do this

So given [92.0, 81.0, 81.0, 41.0, 69.0, 95.0, 82.0, 25.0, 92.0, 18.0, 60.0, 68.0, 29.0, 75.0, 87.0, 24.0, 99.0, 93.0, 76.0, 49.0, 36.0]

the areas after the above list is broken up should be
[3066.9, 1258.5,  986.4,  510.9, 1052.0, 1106.7,  712.6]

Here is another attempt
but it does not work

```
triangle_area :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
triangle_area a b c = sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) where s = (a +     b + c) / 2.0

splitEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitEvery n = takeWhile (not.null) . map (take n) . iterate (drop n)

triangle_areas :: [Double] -> [Double]
triangle_areas [] = []
triangle_areas (a:b:c:xs) = triangle_area a b c : triangle_areas xs
```

basically I want to do splitEvery 3 [1..9] and then take triangle_area on those broken up lists.

***triangle_areas*** currently works perfectly, but I am not able to use recursion so I need to rework.

***WORKING***

```
splitEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitEvery n = takeWhile (not.null) . map (take n) . iterate (drop n)

triangle_area [a,b,c] = sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) 
                    where s = (a + b + c) / 2.0

triangle_areas = map triangle_area . splitEvery 3
```

Thank you very much Chepner

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the question. Given `[1..9]`, the three triangles have sides `[1,2,3]`, `[4,5,6]`, and `[7,8,9]`.

Comment: I think you are correct, i will modify

Comment: I modified my mistakes and added some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the definition of `map` for inspiration.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

`map` applies its function to *one* argument; you want to apply your function to *three* arguments.

```
triangle_areas :: [Double] -> [Double]
triangle_areas xs = map3 triangle_area xs
                    where map3 f (s1:s2:s3:rest) = f s1 s2 s3 : map3 f rest
                          -- map3 _ [s1, s2] = ???
                          -- map3 _ [s1] = ???
                          map3 _ [] = []
```

I made `map3` a partial function, leaving it undefined for lists with 1 or 2 values left over.

---

Your `splitEvery` is OK; you just need to modify the definition of `triangle_area` so that it can take a 3-element list as input.

```
triangle_area [a,b,c] = sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) 
                        where s = (a + b + c) / 2.0
```

Now you can just map it over the output of `splitEvery`.

```
triangle_areas = map triangle_area . splitEvery 3
```

Comment: that looks like map3 is recursive? and I am not able to use recursion

Comment: I have updated my attempt with a working code but I also used recursion and I would be very appreciative if you could help me get the same output without using recursion.

Comment: "No recursion" is an odd requirement in a functional programming language. Would it be correct to say that you are restricted to using the higher-order functions available in the Prelude?

Comment: Is there a way to mark this post "Answered" and to have your post be the go-to ?

Answer (score 0):

The following is not the most elegant but could serve as inspiration (at least it worked with your example):

```
    triangle_areas :: [Double] -> [Double]
    triangle_areas =
      fst .
      foldl (\(r, sides) x ->
              if length sides == 2
              then (r ++ [triangle_area (sides !! 0) (sides !! 1) x], [])
              else (r, sides ++ [x]))
      ([],[])
```

It works by accumulating the calculated areas and the sides of the current triangle whose area is to be calculated next. That is done in the tuple `(r, sides)`. When we got the three sides of a triangle (2 accumulated in the list `sides` and the third in the parameter `x`) we
calculate the area and add it to the result list, otherwise we leave unchanged the result list and add the current side (parameter `x`) to `sides`.